# How to call my local development services in some other system using IP address?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I have developed services using coldfusion for android devices. I want to share this services to android team  by using my IP address. Can anyone suggest me how to do. For testing purpose it is very needed. ( I am using Coldfusion 11)

Regards,
Sruthi M

Comment: What is preventing you from doing what you say you want to do?

Comment: I didn't get your question Dan.

Comment: I want to know how to share the service URL

Comment: From Dev environement it is running by taffy

Comment: You can use ngrok (ngrok.com) to create a tunnel to your local dev instance. When you start ngrok, it will generate a URL that you can share to your team.

Comment: oh! I will try ! Thank you beloitdavisja